# How do I calculate value of prescaler for stm32f334R8?

Tags: stm32

Given are these informations: 
Processor clock 64MHz, AHB  Prescaler = 1, APB1 Prescaler = 2, APB2 Prescaler = 1.

"The pulse generated by the edge must be at least 0.8 μs long. After this, a waiting time of at least 96 μs must be maintained in order to give the hardware enough time to process the data."

How can I calculate with all these informations prescaler and period so to be able to write something like this for every bus:

```
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = x;
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have timer clocks. Depending which timer use appropriate  value of the input clock. So wee need 97us PWM

[image]

Lets use any timer driven by 64MHz clock

ARR will be 97e-6 / (1 / 64e6) = 6207 and CCRx register = 64 
PSC = 0